# How to drop data frame row if there is less than 4 character in sentence column?

Tags: python, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

let's say i have already tokenized sentence in my data frame like this :

```
+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
|                sentence                 | sentiment |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
| [i, like, this, app, it, s, awesome]    | positive  |
| [way, to, many, ads, pop, up, hate, it] | negative  |
| [ye]                                    | negative  |
| [p]                                     | positive  |
| [niceeeee]                              | positive  |
| [i, do, not, like, the, design]         | negative  |
| [very, useful, recommended]             | positive  |
| [ugly]                                  | negative  |
| [xxx]                                   | negative  |
| [yes]                                   | positive  |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
```

I want to clean out unnecessary data from my data frame by removing df row if there is less than 4 character is sentence column, so the end result will be like this :

```
+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
|                sentence                 | sentiment |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
| [i, like, this, app, it, s, awesome]    | positive  |
| [way, to, many, ads, pop, up, hate, it] | negative  |
| [niceeeee]                              | positive  |
| [i, do, not, like, the, design]         | negative  |
| [very, useful, recommended]             | positive  |
| [ugly]                                  | negative  |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
```

is there anyone who can provide the program code to solve this problem? i will really appreciate your help, it will help my thesis work, thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` function for this

```
char_limit=4
df[df['sentence'].apply(lambda x : len("".join(x))>=char_limit)]
```